# Postgres: Search html blob for visible text

Tags: html, postgresql, search

I have a postgresql table that contains 100,000+ rows of cached HTML in a text field.  I need a way of searching that HTML, but ONLY for items that would be visible to the user if that HTML was sent to a browser.

I've looked into xpath, but parsing the HTML using XMLPARSE throws errors (as HTML is not always "well formed XML").  I've also looked into using regular expressions, but have found many reasons (here on stack overflow) why search HTML via regular expressions does not work well.

Thoughts?

Comment: that's not something I'd try to do in a database.  depending on how complicated the HTML is (e.g. CSS rules can hide elements depending on screen size) you might be able to do something in PG, but this is the sort of thing I'd normally pull out into something like Python to work on

Comment: I should note that the stored HTML will be pretty primitive.  No CSS or Javascript that hides/shows/formats text.

Comment: still not something I'd try to do in a database!  why do you want to do it in PG?  maybe do a preprocessing run to clean up the HTML into something PG's XML parser can handle and then you can do things there.  otherwise, just parse out all the visible items and save those for easy searching.  the above can be done in a trigger if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would preprocess the column by removing all tags:

```
regexp_replace(col, '<[^>]*>', '', 'g')
```

Comment: This might be a good idea!  I'll need to strip out some stuff between certain tags as well, like <style>*</style>.  I'll look into this.

Comment: I ended up doing a preprocess step similar to the above: regexp_replace(col, '(?:<style.+?>.+?<\/style>|<script.+?>.+?<\/script>|<(?:!|\/?[a-zA-Z]+)[^>]*?\/?>)', ' ', 'gi')